# Is it possible to add PBIs/tasks to TFS without visual studio?

Tags: tfs, project-management

we're transitioning to doing all our task tracking in TFS 2010 and I'm wondering if there is a more lightweight way of working with it than through Visual Studio?

Just some sort of web-interface or a lightweight client, or even some powershell commandlets where I can create new tasks and add information to existing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [web interface for TFS2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822150%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). [As far as I can tell](http://blogs.msdn.com/hakane/archive/2009/05/19/where-is-team-system-web-access-in-tfs-2010-beta1.aspx) it is included by default with the 2010 edition

Answer (score 3):

You could use a tool called [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/tfs?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMStack). It integrates with TFS allowing to create and manage TFS tasks in a more user-friendly interface. Besides that Eylean offers additional features such as reports, time tracking and others.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [Scrum Taskboard für Team Systems](http://www.scrumforteamsystem.com/en/TaskBoard/Default.aspx) for the Daily Scrum, its easy and fast to change status of SPIs and create new SPIs. There is also a planning mode to add new BPIs.

Answer (score 1):

A other comprehensive tool is [Telerik Work Item Manager](http://www.telerik.com/products/tfsmanager-and-tfsdashboard.aspx). It provides dash board, interactive task board and many ways to sort, filter and grouping items.